# Organization model extends user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have User model and Organization model. The only difference is that organization has_many users, all other properties are same. I don't want to put it in one table/model. How can I remove tons of code duplicating in this models? Should I use Concerns? I think, it will be not normal if User model will looks like :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  include user_concern
end
```

So, how can I extend user model in other model? And how to generate this model with `rails g` with all User's fields inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use single table inheritance (STI) for this. To get it to work, your model needs a `type`-field of type `string`, in which ActiveRecord stores the actual type of your record. Then, you just extend your base model for this.

**migration**
`add_column :users, :type, :string`

**models**
`class User < ActiveRecord::Base` and `class Organisation < User`.

ActiveRecord will now fill your `type`-field with the model-name, and store both in your `users` table (since this is the one the organisation model is inheriting from).

Have a look at the according section on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html .

However, in your case, I'd create a base model, e.g. `Address`, and then extend `User` and `Organisation` from it, to maintain semantically correct models.

Answer (score 2):

### beware STI

I would keep with concerns rather than using STI. STI often causes more problem that it solves (type mismatches, form urls, etc), plus inheritance won't make sense, here : an user is not a kind of company, and a company is not a kind of user.

### That's a naming problem

I think your problem is a naming one. Obviously, your concern should not be "UserConcern". The question is : what kind of methods do you group in that concern ?

Are your methods about social relation between users ? Then, you need a `Socializable` concern. Are they about subscribing to mailing list ? Then you need a `Subscribable` concern.

It's ok to have several ones, even if they have a single method in it, because developers won't wonder "what the hell does this do ?" if all concerns are correctly named.

### What to duplicate anyway

You should also probably let class level method calls out concerns.

If it's ok for scopes to be embedded in concerns (after all, they resolve in method definitions), it feels less natural to me to put relations in there.

It's ok to duplicate `#has_many :foos`, we do it all the time in separate models, and it's already difficult enough to get an idea of table schema from a model without hiding more information.